# custom web component callbacks

Tags: javascript, html, native-web-component

I'm having a hard time explaining this. I'm building out a custom component, in this component there is a button. I need to be able to dynamically set the click action for that button so that its action can change depending on context. so if there are 2 instances of this component, a&b, each instance has a different function that is executed when the button inside them is clicked. I thought I could just assign a function to a property of the component and execute the property from inside the component like this:

```js
window.customElements.define('xmp-1', class xmp1 extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){super();}
  connectedCallback(){
    this.innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <div id='test' style='width:70px; border:solid thin black;'>test button</div>
      </div>`;
    this.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', function(){
      console.log('test action');
      this.action1();
    });
  }
});

document.querySelector('xmp-1').action1 = function(){
  console.log("this is the callback");
};
```

```html
<xmp-1></xmp-1>
```

but when you run this you get an error saying the property `action1` doesn't exist.

Whats the proper way to setup a callback that allows the flexibility I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Please try the below code, where I have added a binding statement to bind **"this"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <xmp-1></xmp-1>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('xmp-1').action1 = function(){
            console.log("this is the callback");
        };
        window.customElements.define('xmp-1', class xmp1 extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() { super(); 
                this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
            }
            handler() {
                console.log("this is the test");
                console.log('test action');
                this.action1();
            }

            connectedCallback() {
                this.innerHTML = `<div>
                    <div id='test' style='width:70px; border:solid thin black;'>test button</div>
                    </div>`;
                this.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click',this.handler);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please change **xmp-1** to **#test** in your code as shown below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <xmp-1></xmp-1>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {

            document.querySelector('#test').action1 = function(){
                console.log("this is the callback");
            };

        });
        window.customElements.define('xmp-1', class xmp1 extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() { super(); }

            connectedCallback() {
                this.innerHTML = `<div>
                    <div id='test' style='width:70px; border:solid thin black;'>test button</div>
                    </div>`;
                this.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    console.log('test action');
                    this.action1();
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or please try approach2 as shown below, where you must add a function called **this.querySelector('#test').action1** to your custom element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <xmp-1></xmp-1>
    <script>
        window.customElements.define('xmp-1', class xmp1 extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() { super(); }

            connectedCallback() {
                this.innerHTML = `<div>
                    <div id='test' style='width:70px; border:solid thin black;'>test button</div>
                    </div>`;
                this.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', function () {
                    console.log('test action');
                    this.action1();
                });
                this.querySelector('#test').action1 = function() {
                    console.log('test action1');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that defeats the purpose. I need to be able to set the function from outside of the component.

Comment: also, in my actual code I am using an id, but in the example it isnt necessary because I'm selecting the tag directly since there is only one of them.

Comment: Thats what it was, I was missing the binding on the function. Thank you.

Comment: also, in my original example I had an anonymous function attached to the click event rather than referencing the callback directly. That made that code block loose proper reference when using this.